# how to convert date to another format using moment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to convert my date into another format using `moment` `lib`
I tried like that but not getting expected output

here is my code

https://jsbin.com/kowuzaraju/edit?html,js,output

```
var date ="24 May 2017, 05:35";

//expected date using moment
var expectedDate="May 24, 2017, 05.35AM IST"
var a = moment(date,'mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm')
var b = moment(date).format('mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm')

//alert(a)
//alert('b')
```

**var expectedDate="May 24, 2017, 05.35AM IST"**

Comment: `format` does not have an `e` at the end, although other than that, I'm not familiar enough with momentjs to help you any further.

Comment: See moment [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), tokens are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to parse your input string using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) method. In your case, you can use `'DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm'` as second parameter (`DD` day of the month, `MMM` month's name, `YYYY` year, `HH` 0-23 hour, `mm` minutes).

Then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show moment object in the desired format.

Here a working sample:

```js
var date ="24 May 2017, 05:35";
//var expectedDate="May 24, 2017, 05.35AM IST"
var a = moment(date,'DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm')
var b = a.format('MMM DD, YYYY, hh.mmA')
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that, by default, moment parses time in local time, you have to use use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) if you have to convert between zones. If you want to show `IST` you can use the `z` token inside `format()`, as the doc says:

> **Note:** as of 1.6.0, the z/zz format tokens have been deprecated from plain moment objects. [Read more about it here.](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162) However, they *do* work if you are using a specific time zone with the moment-timezone addon.

Here a sample using moment-timezone:

```js
var date ="24 May 2017, 05:35";
// Parse input specifying Asia/Kolkata timezone
var a = moment.tz(date, 'DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm', 'Asia/Kolkata');
// Format moment uzing z to show the timezone
var b = a.format('MMM DD, YYYY, hh.mmA z')
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```